# How convert json in array by JS

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert JSON data from

```
  [{"Date":"2014","Amount1":90,"Amount2":800},    {"Date":"2015","Amount1":110,"Amount2":300},{"Date":"2016","Amount1":3000,"Amount2":500}]
```

to

```
[['Date', 'Amount1', 'Amount2'],
      ['2014',  90,      800],
      ['2015',  110,      300],
      ['2016',  3000,       500]]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you tried ? Moreover, I don't think expected output will be helpful.. Just `JSON.parse` will return good enough result to be read..

Comment: Nothing, cos I don't know how

Comment: Then ask yourself, "do i need to do this in first place" and go to mva js course or even better google the definitive guide ;) and mdn

Comment: Well, if you don't know how, that's when you do *research*. There's a **huge** amount of information on the web and on SO specifically about how to loop through arrays, create objects, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** and **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** methods.

```js
var data = [{
  "Date": "2014",
  "Amount1": 90,
  "Amount2": 800
}, {
  "Date": "2015",
  "Amount1": 110,
  "Amount2": 300
}, {
  "Date": "2016",
  "Amount1": 3000,
  "Amount2": 500
}];

// iterate over the array value
var res = data.reduce(function(arr, o) {
  // push the new value to array
  arr.push(
    // generate object value array using the key array
    arr[0].map(function(k) {
      // return the property value
      return o[k]
    })
  );
  // return the updated array
  return arr;
  // set initial variable as array with
  // fist element as object property array
}, [Object.keys(data[0])]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: `reduce`? What do you need `reduce` for? This is a straightforward application of `map`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :  element at index `0` is property names of the object.... I think in this particular way there is no need of additional array for storing the property name

Comment: Enh, maybe, `reduce` seems an odd tool here. I'd've probably sliced and mapped. Anyway, until/unless OP demonstrates some attempt...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I think any other method may require an additional variable.....  not sure :)

Comment: Thx for everybody and  Pranav C Balan
i've got an error TypeError: Object.keys: argument is not an Object

Comment: @Tim-Tim :  the argument should be the first element in the array .... in my example `data[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a helper array for the keys, that keeps the wanted order of the properties and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the values. Then apply the keys to the beginning of the array.

```js
var data = [{ "Date": "2014", "Amount1": 90, "Amount2": 800 }, { "Date": "2015", "Amount1": 110, "Amount2": 300 }, { "Date": "2016", "Amount1": 3000, "Amount2": 500 }],
    keys = Object.keys(data[0]),
    result = data.map(function (o) {
        return keys.map(function (k) {
            return o[k];
        });
    });

result.unshift(keys);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var data = [{ "Date": "2014", "Amount1": 90, "Amount2": 800 }, { "Date": "2015", "Amount1": 110, "Amount2": 300 }, { "Date": "2016", "Amount1": 3000, "Amount2": 500 }],
    keys = Object.keys(data[0]),
    result = data.map(o => keys.map(k => o[k]));

result.unshift(keys);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thx, but in general i don't know about keys, it can dynamically changes

Comment: Thx but I've got an error Object.keys: argument is not an Object

Comment: maybe you have a string and you need to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it first.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just loop 2 times threw your JSON object

```
var obj = [{"Date":"2014","Amount1":90,"Amount2":800},{"Date":"2015","Amount1":110,"Amount2":300},{"Date":"2016","Amount1":3000,"Amount2":500}];
var result = [];
result.push(Object.keys(obj[0]));
for (var subObj in obj){
  var arr = [];
  for (var item in obj[subObj])  arr.push(obj[subObj][item]);
  result.push(arr);
}
console.log(result); // [ [ 'Date', 'Amount1', 'Amount2' ],[ '2014', 90, 800 ],[ '2015', 110, 300 ],[ '2016', 3000, 500 ] ]
```